# Call Method on application launching in Windows Phone SDK 7.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I need to call a method normally fired by a button of the mainpage.xaml, when the application start.
Do I need to use the Application_Launching method of the app.xaml? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your goal should be to display MainPage.xaml as-soon-as-possible.

Rather than actually calling the method, you should just set a boolean that indicates you *should* call it, and then call the method inside your MainPage.xaml.cs (or however your project is structured).

App.xaml.cs:

```
public static bool IsInitialLaunch = true;
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

Loaded Event:

```
if (App.IsInitialLaunch){
   SomeMethod();
   App.IsInitialLaunch = false;
}
```